# The logo of the navbar of my website disappear

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, tumblr

I try to do a blog using tumblr regardless of my website who is a wordpress website

Here is my website: http://www.appyourself.com/

And here my blog: http://blog.appyourself.com

As you can see I took the same structure of my website and i copy it on my tumblr theme

Only I have a problem the logo you can see on the site left navigation bar does not appear on the blog

I'm looking with "inspect the element" of the element and even parents, css properties are the same

```
<a href="http://www.appyourself.com/" class="navbar-brand">
<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/dbi5jhw/fJomyz3ui/logo-appyourself.png"></img>
</a>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code here. Once the problem is fixed, the question no longer has any relevance.

Comment: 96 css warnings?Maybe post some questions for these first?

Comment: @laaposto Strange. I didn't get any CSS errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logo is under the menu, for some reason.
To reveal it, add this:

```
.navbar-header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Or even better, you can remove the menu background color:

bootstrap.min.css line 16
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form
delete background color from this class

Answer (score 0):

it is because your nav bars width overlapped with the logo also please try to reduce the size of the nav bar.

Comment: Why reduce? It looks good like that. You just might need a larger monitor :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in css

```
.navbar .navbar-nav li a { 
   word-spacing: 0px;
}
```